# Viewing Deep Learning as an optimization problem, and general theorems on Duality.

Tags: optimization, duality-theorems, neural-networks

In optimization problems of the type LP, we have methods like the simplex algorithm. The integer version of the problem is I believe NP-complete, but we know that a solution exists and we can find it in finite steps. However, no such guarantee exists in Deep Neural networks. It's not clear these networks even optimize the objective function. It's not clear if backpropagation finds the global minimum, or even if a finite number of minimum points exist, or it even converges.

But I do find Duality Theory appealing. However, (I think) that the duality theorems only apply to certain cases of optimization problems (linear and I believe convex?). Deep Neural Networks (I believe) have a few nice properties, they are continuous and differentiable everywhere, I'm not sure about the behavior of the 2nd derivative. I know it's a non-convex function. Is there a more general version of Duality that can apply to Deep Neural Networks?

Comment: If you're using the ReLU activation function, then the neural network is not actually differentiable. (But, it seems that this is not a problem in practice.)

Comment: By the way, when you're minimizing empirical risk with a large number of parameters, it's not even clear that you *want* to find the global minimum, which probably overfits to the training data. You'd rather have an optimization method that performs implicit regularization, like stochastic gradient descent.

Comment: @ChrisCulter what is the explicit meaning of regularization? Can it be viewed as finding the weights of a neural network that minimize empirical risk and variation of the function simultaneously?

Comment: @SpentDeath I don't know how to formulate the true variance as a function of the weights. There are explicit regularizers of the weights which, when minimized, have the effect of reducing variance, but that isn't quite the same.

Comment: @ChrisCulter Question: rather than regularizing implicitly by stopping the optimization algorithm early, is it not better to just add a sufficiently strong regularization term to the objective function so that we do want to truly solve the resulting optimization problem (in the sense of finding a local minimum)? In the early days of classical image deblurring, "stopping early" was used as a regularization technique, but later this was abandoned in favor of using regularization terms like wavelet regularization. I wonder if we are not in a similar situation with neural networks.

Comment: @littleO (I can't begin to address this question, so I just wanted to say, thank you for your insight!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can interpret fitting a neural network as a non-convex optimization problem, and whenever there is a primal optimization problem there is of course a dual problem. However, while we will definitely have weak duality, there is no guarantee that strong duality holds between the primal and dual problems here (and in fact it doesn't in general). Since there are positive duality gaps, duality theory is arguably not that useful in this case.

To answer what I think you are really asking here: deep learning tends to work quite well because fitting weights to neural networks is equivalent to a non-convex optimization problem where lots of local minima turn out to be near globally optimal; see for instance [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.0233).

In terms of certifying optimality, you can think about attempting to reduce the duality gap between the primal and dual problems by introducing auxillary variables, alla the [Lasserre](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~rothvoss/lecturenotes/lasserresurvey.pdf) hierarchy (although this is mainly of theoretical interest, since it turns out to not be very tractable).

Comment: Training a neural network is an unconstrained optimization problem, so there does not seem to be an interesting dual problem. (But correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: Oh sorry, I guess I wasn't clear. I was asking if a more general duality theorem exists that can be applied to deep learning. The motivation for this is to take inspiration from the simplex algorithm, and construct an alternative to backpropagation.

Comment: @littleO I agree that the dual problem will not be interesting in the original space. However, if we add auxiliary variables then we might obtain a more interesting problem in a higher dimensional space (with constraints linking the new and auxiliary variables), and there may be a more interesting dual associated with this problem.